# how to make refrences of hashmap/arraylist null in java to release all memory

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Does `HashMap.clear()` or `ArrayList.clear()` releases memory to shrink the size or the size remains the same?

How arraylist or hashmap references can be made `null` to be allowed for gc.

Answer (score 6):

If you `clear()` your `Map` or `Collection`, then the garbage collector can collect the objects that were contained in it, as long as they aren't referenced elsewhere. Same with removing all references to the `Map` or `Collection` itself (by setting it to `null` everywhere): As long as the `Map`, for example, was the only Object "knowing" these references, removing all references to the `Map` itself will allow the garbage collector to collect the `Map` and thus also the objects contained in it (as long as they aren't referenced elsewhere, of course).

But just clearing the Map does not guarantee that the garbage collector will actually run - it just CAN clear these objects from memory, IF it runs. But typically you shouldn't worry about that. So you will in all likelyhood not notice a direct and immediate memory gain from calling `clear()`, but only because the garbage collector does not run all the time.

Comment: Agreed, All you need do is call clear(), and let the GC do it's job when it needs to +1

Comment: May be worth adding that it can often be quicker to just let go of the Collection. Setting it to `= new Xxx();` can often be quicker than clearing.

Comment: Possibly true, because `clear()` obviously has to do some work. On the other hand, we are talking about quite trivial tasks here, typically `clear()` should not take that much longer than `new ...`, at least not longer enough to justify premature optimization, I guess. If it DOES take that much longer, one should think about if the work it does is actually useful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Calling clear will remove all elements of the collection, if you have no other references to the objects from the collection will make them eligible for garbage collecting.

Assigning null to your collection will do essentially the same as above however it will affect your collection too. If there are no further references to that collection it will become unreachable and eligible for garbage collecting. If you don't keep other references to objects from that collection they can also be garbage collected.